# jpql SUM one column

Tags: java, jpql

I am trying to add up all the prices in one column, but it outputs a ridiculous total. Please help, not sure if my query is incorrect. Thanks.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Tyrerange.totalCost", query = "SELECT SUM(t.dblTyreCost) FROM Tyrerange t"),    

double totalCost = (double) em.createNamedQuery("Tyrerange.totalCost").getSingleResult();

document.add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf((df.format(totalCost)))));
```

Comment: I would say this is ok. Print totalCost before formatting, maybe your formatter is badly configured.

Comment: It isn't the formatting, although it's strange, it doesn't matter whether i change the prices in the database, it still prints the exact amount ;S

Comment: It could be reading cached values. Create a new query and sum some other column.

Comment: You should mark @alterfox's answer as correct... It actually pointed you towards the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks ok. Maybe the cached values are being read. Create a new query and sum some other column to check this.